# C++ opencv custom threshold

Tags: c++, opencv

I need a custom threshold to the image, where is the value of the pixel is less than **thr** I need to leave the original value, but if the pixel is bigger than the **thr** then it should be the same value of the **thr**.

I check the threshold method in the opencv, but it give me back and white, I do not want this, I need the same what I explain above.

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Try the reference - first result for a search of 'openCV threshold' took me straight to the page that @Hazem pulled those images from ...

Comment: image.setTo(thr, img>thr); if img is single channel image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opencv offer you some basic thresholding operations, We can effectuate 5 types of Thresholding operations:

**Threshold Binary:**

[image]

[image]

if the intensity of the pixel src(x,y) is higher than thresh, then the new pixel intensity is set to a MaxVal. Otherwise, the pixels are set to 0.

**Threshold Binary, Inverted:**

[image]

[image]

If the intensity of the pixel src(x,y) is higher than thresh, then the new pixel intensity is set to a 0. Otherwise, it is set to MaxVal.

**Truncate:**

[image]

[image]

The maximum intensity value for the pixels is thresh, if src(x,y) is greater, then its value is truncated.

**Threshold to Zero:**

[image]

[image]

If src(x,y) is lower than thresh, the new pixel value will be set to 0.

**Threshold to Zero, Inverted:**

[image]

[image]

If src(x,y) is greater than thresh, the new pixel value will be set to 0.

**So** you can do that using `Truncated` type, check this:

```
double threshold(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, double thresh, double maxval, int type)

src – input array (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit floating point).
dst – output array of the same size and type as src.
thresh – threshold value.
maxval – maximum value to use with the THRESH_BINARY and THRESH_BINARY_INV thresholding types.
type – thresholding type (see the details below).
```

Example:

```
/*  threshold_type
     0: Binary
     1: Binary Inverted
     2: Threshold Truncated
     3: Threshold to Zero
     4: Threshold to Zero Inverted
   */
  threshold( src_gray, dst, threshold_value, max_BINARY_value,threshold_type );
//In your case threshold_type = 2
```

ref: [1](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) [2](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold)